# Unicode - ICU library - get a count of codepoints in UnicodeString

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

I have started with ICU library in C++.

```
UnicodeString ucs = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(u8"\U0001F674"));
ucs = ucs.unescape();
size_t len = ucs.length();
```

However, `len = 2`. Why? I have added only one 4 byte character (https://unicode-table.com/en/1F674/). Is there a way, how to return correct length?

I expect the length to be 1, since there is only 1 codepoint. If I use

```
UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(u8"\u06b5"));
ucs = ucs.unescape();
size_t len = ucs.length();
```

I get correct `len = 1`

Comment: What "length" are you trying to get exactly? The UTF-8 length (4)? The UTF-16 length (2)? The codepoint length (1)? Please clarify your question. What are you *expecting* to get?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Edited question

Comment: @MartinPerry: There is pretty much *never* a reason to know the number of code points in a Unicode-encoded string. What are you *really* trying to do that you feel you need this information?

Comment: @NicolBolas I want to use this for font rendering with FreeType2 and I need number of "letters" that will be rendered in a line, co I can compute other things.

Comment: @MartinPerry: The count of the codepoints will *not* give you the "number of 'letters'". That count ignores combining characters and other Unicode eccentricities. What you want is a count of grapheme clusters. But even the *count* of such clusters is only relevant if its a fixed-width font (and not even then, since there are non-visible codepoints).

Answer (score 4):

`UnicodeString` uses UTF-16, not UTF-8.

In UTF-16, codepoint `U+1F674` requires two 2-byte codeunits: `0xD83D 0xDE74`.  And codepoint `U+06B5` requires only one 2-byte codeunit: `0x06B5`.

Comment: So, there is no way? I have tried to recompile with `U_CHARSET_IS_UTF8`, but it has no effect.

Comment: Perhaps ICU has a type similar to UnicodeString except using utf-8 internally but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: I was looking for this, but found nothing. I know, that there is tinyutf8 library (nothing in common with ICU), but using several libraries does not seem like a good idea to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, in order to get the number of code points in a UnicodeString, use [UnicodeString::countChar32](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#abb7390ae3beff120d9f89ea93c251514).

-- Shane (from the ICU team)